# undefined method `trigger' for Pusher:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pusher

I am just getting started with the pusher

In config/initializers/pusher.rb

```
require 'pusher'

Pusher.app_id = 'xxx'
Pusher.key = 'xxx'
Pusher.secret = 'xxx'
Pusher.logger = Rails.logger
Pusher.encrypted = true
```

In the application.html.erb

```
// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('xxx', {
  encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
});
```

In the controller

require 'pusher'

```
class CheckPushController < ApplicationController
  def show
    Pusher.trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', {
      message: 'hello world'
    })
  end
end
```

I used the same, in the dashboard I was able to send a trigger to test_channel. However when reloaded the page, I am getting

```
undefined method `trigger' for Pusher:Module
```

Comment: It's weird that `trigger` doesn't work! In `config/initializers/pusher.rb` instead of using the global Pusher namespace (which is deprecated) please create a new instance, see https://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide#/lang=rb

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vamsipavanmahesh/f92896b6fc40b9c8a6c66f25f3578822 is resulting in uninitialized constant Pusher::Client

Comment: You could always just use the Ably Ruby library. **Huge disclaimer** I am the author of the Ably ruby client library https://github.com/ably/ably-ruby, so  I rate it :)

Comment: @MatthewO'Riordan I will surely have a look :)